# ReactJS rendering Issue fetching an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch a WeatherApp API, using Geolocation.
My problem is the rendering:
It doesn't allow me to render the page before I fetch (but after I somehow manage to fetch, the code seems to work).

Returning Error message:

```
Type Error : Cannot Read Property 'temp' of undefined
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const [ positionLat, setPositionLat ] = useState('') ;
  const [ positionLong, setPositionLong] = useState('') ;
  
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    setPositionLat(position.coords.latitude);
    setPositionLong(position.coords.longitude);
  });

  const [weather, setWeather] = useState('');

  const fetchingWeather = () => {
    Axios.get(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${positionLat}&lon=${positionLong}&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.main.temp)
      setWeather(res.data)
    })
  }

// this line is returning the error 
 console.log(weather.main.temp)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>lattitude :{positionLat}</p>
      <p>longitude :{positionLong}</p>
      <button onClick={fetchingWeather}>Cliquez moi pour fetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous; your `console.log` will run before the request has completed.

Comment: You don't set the `weather` state until you execute `fetchingWeather()` and you only call that when clicking the button. The `console` line in question runs when your component renders so `weather` is only going to be an empty string at that stage. That being said, you're not using `weather` anywhere do it's entirely unclear what the problem is

Comment: but how I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Fetching weather and setting weather state is asynchronous, your are console logging `weather.main.temp` before the request has completed. And fetching data is side effect in reactjs. So you are suggested to fetch weather info by using `useEffect` hooks and set weather state there.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const [ positionLat, setPositionLat ] = useState('') ;
  const [ positionLong, setPositionLong] = useState('') ;
  
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    setPositionLat(position.coords.latitude);
    setPositionLong(position.coords.longitude);
  });

  const [weather, setWeather] = useState('');

  const fetchingWeather = () => {
    Axios.get(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${positionLat}&lon=${positionLong}&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.main.temp)
      setWeather(res.data)
    })
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchingWeather();
  }, [weather])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>lattitude :{positionLat}</p>
      <p>longitude :{positionLong}</p>
      <button onClick={fetchingWeather}>Cliquez moi pour fetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

That should work.

Comment: Nah it's same error. I'm checking useEffects, but I have watched 3 or 4 tutorials about that, and I already played with it. But here it's already too complex for me.